How can I export my Google Colab notebook to Excel?
I did some data analysis on Google Xolab, and now I want to export the finished table into Excel. It doesn't let me directly download to my downloads (or other folders). I guess this is because it is a Google product. How can I export this into my Google Drive?
I tried exporting using this function:
final_df.to_excel('/Users/jeff/Downloads/merged_data.xlsx', index=False, sheet_name='Summary')

what can I put in the file path instead of my Mac info?

I don't think you can export the file directly to your local system from Google Collab.
One of the common approach is to mount Google Drive in Google Colab.
And then saving your file to Google Drive is recommended.
You do something like below:
from google.colab import drive drive.mount('/content/drive') ##you will need to authenticate using an authorization code. Content/ drive is the default folder.

And then use the export function you were trying earlier
Final_df.to_excel('/content/drive/My Drive/folder to save/merged_data.xlsx', index=False, sheet_name='summary');

